# Is there a CommonJS/require() implementation that doesn't use `module.exports`?

Tags: javascript, commonjs

Are there any build tools or JS-environments that use *only* the `exports`-variable *and not* `module.exports`, when doing a CommonJS-like `require()`? (i.e. disregard AMD/RequireJS)

**Background**
The [CommonJS specification](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1.1) only defines the `exports` variable – it never mentions `module.exports` – however when most people write about CommonJS<sup>1</sup>, they assume that it's possible to use `module.exports` rather than `exports`, as popularized by Node.js. My general impression is that most so-called "CommonJS" implementations support `module.exports`.

This is relevant to me as the [UMD-template for jQuery-plugins](https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/95563fd6b46f06bda0af143ff67292e7f6ede6b7/templates/jqueryPlugin.js) only checks `module.exports`, whereas most of [the other CommonJS UMD-templates](https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/95563fd6b46f06bda0af143ff67292e7f6ede6b7/templates/commonjsStrict.js) actually check the `exports`-variable (and thus conform to the CommonJS-spec). So which one is it – can I move to fully ignoring `exports` and only check for `module.exports` – or do I really need to check `exports` to have my library support all possible clients?

**References**
<sup>1</sup> [dontkry.com](http://dontkry.com/posts/code/browserify-and-the-universal-module-definition.html), [freecodecamp.com](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/javascript-modules-a-beginner-s-guide-783f7d7a5fcc#.jhzb22f5i), [Brian Leroux](https://medium.com/@brianleroux/es6-modules-amd-and-commonjs-c1acefbe6fc0#.ybs1xkr3p), [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383795/difference-between-module-exports-and-exports-in-the-commonjs-module-system) [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066527/commonjs-modules-exporting-a-function-that-returns-a-function-with-arguments?rq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160956/is-module-exports-in-commonjs-equal-to-export-in-es6)

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7142924/2581562) helps:

Comment: @Legends: Hi – sorry – it doesn't. The question is not about the difference between `exports` and `module.exports`, but rather whether I will ever run in to a situation where `module.exports` is unavailable (and only `exports` is available)